# Why is this SSE2 code performing inconsistently?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, icc

As a learning exercise I'm trying my hand at speeding up matrix multiplication code using SIMD on various architectures. I'm having a weird issue with my 3D matrix multiplication code for SSE2 where its performance jumps between two extremes, either ~5ms (expected) or ~100ms for 1 million operations.

The only thing "bad" that this code is doing is the unaligned stores/loads and the hack at the end to store a vector into memory without the 4th element trampling memory. This would explain some performance variance, but the fact that the performance difference is so large makes me suspect I'm missing something important.

I've tried a couple of things but I'll have another crack at it after some sleep.

See code below. The m_matrix variable is aligned on the 16 byte boundary.

```
void Matrix3x3::MultiplySSE2(Matrix3x3 &other, Matrix3x3 &output)
{
    __m128 a_row, r_row;
    __m128 a1_row, r1_row;
    __m128 a2_row, r2_row;

    const __m128 b_row0 = _mm_load_ps(&other.m_matrix[0]);
    const __m128 b_row1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&other.m_matrix[3]);
    const __m128 b_row2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&other.m_matrix[6]);

    // Perform dot products with first row
    a_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[0]);
    r_row = _mm_mul_ps(a_row, b_row0);
    a_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[1]);
    r_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a_row, b_row1), r_row);
    a_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[2]);
    r_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a_row, b_row2), r_row);

    _mm_store_ps(&output.m_matrix[0], r_row);

    // Perform dot products with second row
    a1_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[3]);
    r1_row = _mm_mul_ps(a1_row, b_row0);
    a1_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[4]);
    r1_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a1_row, b_row1), r1_row);
    a1_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[5]);
    r1_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a1_row, b_row2), r1_row);

    _mm_storeu_ps(&output.m_matrix[3], r1_row);

    // Perform dot products with third row
    a2_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[6]);
    r2_row = _mm_mul_ps(a2_row, b_row0);
    a2_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[7]);
    r2_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a2_row, b_row1), r2_row);
    a2_row = _mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[8]);
    r2_row = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a2_row, b_row2), r2_row);

    // Store only the first 3 elements in a vector so we dont trample memory
    _mm_store_ss(&output.m_matrix[6], _mm_shuffle_ps(r2_row, r2_row,        _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    _mm_store_ss(&output.m_matrix[7], _mm_shuffle_ps(r2_row, r2_row, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)));
    _mm_store_ss(&output.m_matrix[8], _mm_shuffle_ps(r2_row, r2_row, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)));
}
```

Comment: Do 1 million tests a few times and get the average time. Doing the test just once will give you unreliable results.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I am taking the average already as part of the test bench. The average time is still an anomaly compared to 2D and 4D matrices with SSE2.  The stepping behaviour can't be explained away with statistics, the code is faulty.

Comment: Idk, man. If it works, I wouldn't say that it's faulty. How come you're doing an unaligned store btw?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode The rows of a 3x3 matrix have a stride of 12 bytes, but aligned instructions in SSE requires addresses to be aligned on the 16 byte boundary. So after the first row, we can't use aligned load/stores.

Comment: This is why I'd recommend using only 4x4 or 3x4 matrices, unless you are _really_ constrained for space. In another area: Are you running these tests with other threads touching the same data? Of course, this opens up a number of other questions, such as what architecture, etc... Just to narrow this down, try an aligned-only variant that operates on suitably sized data.

Comment: @defube but going the easy route is no fun. ;)

I plan to try using an aligned only approach that uses more shuffles and less loads/stores. I'll have to see how that goes.

Comment: Generally 3x3 is difficult to do well. For the [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) library, the matrix multiply is always 4x4, but there are functions to load/store to a 3x3 (and 3x4) matrix in a data structure. In fact, you should take a look at DirectXMath as all the implementation is done in intrinsics and is fully inline.

Comment: The fact that you are making heavy use of ``mm_set1_ps``, unaligned loads, and scalar stores means the implementation is missing a lot of potential performance. If ``m_matrix`` is always guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned, then a 4x4 matrix is going to take up the same space as all that padding and it's much better suited to SSE/SSE2.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind about SIMD: Doing an operation on 9 floats from memory and then writing them back to memory is not going to benefit much at all and certainly get nothing close to the theoretical 4x speed-up. You need to load the data from memory, do a lot of SIMD-friendly computation with it, and then write the results out. Otherwise, any speed-up you get from a few SIMD multiplies and adds is lost in overload of loading and storing the data anyhow. This is why DirectXMath is all inline and the functions consume/return ``XMVECTOR``/``XMMATRIX`` so the compiler will merge them.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I definitely understand why a production implementation would use 3x4 matricies and spend so much effort forcing the compiler to merge registers. This was more an exercise in what/why. After trying three implementations of pure 3x3 code, the 3x4 code was faster and didn't suffer from the weird performance degradation. So I guess I'll just drop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A performance hit like that sounds like your data is maybe crossing a page line sometimes, not just a cache-line.  If you're testing on a buffer of many different matrices, rather than the same small matrix repeatedly, maybe something else running on another CPU core is pushing your buffer out of L3?

performance issues in your code (which don't explain the factor-of-20 variance.  These should always be slow):

`_mm_set1_ps(m_matrix[3])` and so on is going to be a problem.  It takes a `pshufd` or `movaps + shufps` to broadcast an element.  I think this is unavoidable for matmuls, though.

Storing the final 3 elements without writing past the end:  Try `PALIGNR` to get the last element of the previous row into a reg with the last row.  Then you can do a single unaligned store, which overlaps with the preceding store.  This is a lot fewer shuffles, and is probably faster than `movss` / `extractps` / `extractps`.

If you want to try something with fewer unaligned 16B stores, try `movss`, shuffle or right-shift by 4 bytes (`psrldq` aka `_mm_bsrli_si128`), then `movq` or `movsd` to store the last 8 bytes in one go.  (byte-wise shift is on the same execution port as shuffles, unlike the per element bit-shifts)

Why did do you do *three* `_mm_shuffle_ps` (`shufps`)?  The low element is already the one you want, for the first column of the last row.  Anyway, I think `extractps` is faster than shuffle + store, on non-AVX where preserving the source from being clobbered by `shufps` takes a move.  `pshufd` would work.)

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that it really depends on *exactly* which instruction sets you are able to use. Sticking with just SSE/SSE2 only is limiting, but has broad compatibility--x64 native requires it for example, so all x64-capable CPUs must support it. However, there are a lot of [useful instructions sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse-sse2-and-arm-neon.aspx) beyond SSE2.

Comment: Yeah, the AVX 3-operand version of `shufps` would make for more efficient broadcasting of single elements.  You could do 2 16B loads and an 8B load of the left hand side, so `m_matrix[]` is in 3 registers.  Although with AVX, `VBROADCASTSS` from memory is only a single uop that doesn't even need the shuffle ports at all.  `_mm_set1_ps` compiles to that with AVX, on gcc.  FMA would reduce the number of uops, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll keep this in mind, but I'm going to discard this implementation and try another approach.

Comment: Probably a good call.  There have been lots of questions about short vectors / matrices on here recently, some with interesting answers.  I forget the details, because it wasn't directly relevant to me right then!

Comment: Imma mark this as the answer anyway, it had good advice for dealing with the implementation (even though it's flawed)